# My App Keeps Crashing When I Try to Create an Open GL ES Enviroment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es-2.0

I am following the android tutorial on how to create your own Open GL ES enviroment with graphics. Besides the fact that it seems as though the tutorial is skipping out on code they assume we will know to include, I'm having problems just getting my app to stay open without the error message, "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped" five seconds after the app opens. I don't believe it's the triangle class causing this, because I commented out the triangle object and tried to run it again, but the same thing happens. I also included the necessary code that should be included in the manifest as well.

Here's my code(The Open GL ES code is between the dotted lines) :

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
private GLSurfaceView.Renderer MyRenderer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGLView=new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

//....................................................................................................
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);
        MyRenderer=new MyGlRenderer();
        setRenderer(MyRenderer);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}

//Triangle mTriangle;

public class MyGlRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config){
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        //mTriangle= new Triangle();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused){

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //mTriangle.draw();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height){
        GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    }

}

public class Triangle{

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX=3;
    float triangleCoords[]={
        0.0f, 0.622008459f, 0.0f,//top
        -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, //bottom left
        0.5f, -0.311004242f,0.0f//bottom right
    };

    int mProgram;
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
            "}";

        private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

    public Triangle(){
        ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                triangleCoords.length*4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer=bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader=loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader=loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }

    public int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
        int shader=GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }

    static final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 3;
    static final int vertexCount = 3;


    public void draw(){
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        int mPositionHandle= GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                      vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        int mColorHandle=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color,0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
//....................................................................................................
    }
```

And here's the log act for anyone who needs it:

> 06-23 11:44:30.385: **D**/ActivityThread(27794): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
>   06-23 11:44:30.385: **D**/ActivityThread(27794): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
>   06-23 11:44:30.385: **D**/ActivityThread(27794): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **W**/dalvikvm(27794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ee7438)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp5/com.example.myapp5.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.checkRenderThreadState(GLSurfaceView.java:1810)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(GLSurfaceView.java:472)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.example.myapp5.MainActivity$MyGLSurfaceView.(MainActivity.java:80)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at com.example.myapp5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>   06-23 11:44:30.535: **E**/AndroidRuntime(27794):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setEGLContextClientVersion()` needs to be called before `setRenderer()`, as specified in the documentation: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLContextClientVersion(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLContextClientVersion%28int%29) .

There's also a hint that this is in your problem in the stack trace you copied:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance.